# transparency issues with denoisers

Tags: rendering, denoise

When rendering an image of an object set unto a transparent background, it is observed around the edges of such object that small pixel-sized artifacts appear beyond the 0 opacity boundary. Color is being written to such pixels even though they are transparent- and the color being written is wrong even, with pixels appearing to be colors they should not. This issue only occurs when a denoiser is used.

[image: image zoomed in and brought into GIMP, alpha channel disabled.]

What could be causing this and how can it be avoided?

Blender version 3.6

Comment: It would be helpful if you formed an actual question in addition to just presenting an issue. Also you should describe how exactly you are rendering the image, share screenshots of your render settings, [include a .blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/) with minimal setup to reproduce the issue if possible.

Comment: To replicate: Add a plane, solidify it, add a bunch of subdivisions. Enable the denoiser, turn on transparency in the film settings, crank samples up to 512. Render, open image in editing software(e.g gimp), observe results.